# Pass List<int> from code behind to use in Javascript function

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

Currently I have a Javascript function that uses I can hard code values in like -

```
data: [1,4,7,9]
```

However I wish to pass in an integer list to set the values from the code behind something like -

**C# Code Behind**

```
public List<int> listOfInts = new List<int>();

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listOfInts.Add(1);
        listOfInts.Add(4);
        listOfInts.Add(7);
        listOfInts.Add(9);

        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "blah", "JSfunction()", true);
    }
```

**Aspx**

```
data: <% = listOfInts %>
```

However this breaks with the error -

```
0x800a1391 - Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'JSfunction' is undefined
```

If I remove the aforementioned line and do it like this in the function (not passing anything from the code behind like I need to) -

```
var listOfInts = new Array(); 
listOfInts[0] = 1;
listOfInts[1] = 2; 
listOfInts[2] = 3; 
listOfInts[3] = 4;
```

and then set -

```
data: [listOfInts[0],listOfInts[1],listOfInts[2],listOfInts[3]]
```

This works fine. How can I pass the values from the code behind to populate the values in the Javascript function?

Comment: Try converting it to JSON instead of just sending javascript your .Net object.

Comment: I didn't have time to throw the code together earlier... but take a look at my answer below the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to format listOfInts as a javascript array. Try adding a property in your code-behind like this:

```
protected string IntsAsJSArray
{   
    get 
    {
        return string.Format("[{0}]", string.Join(",", listOfInts));
    }
}
```

Then in your ASPX page

```
data: <%= IntsAsJSArray %>
```

Answer (score 2):

A more generic method to do this... and significantly better in my opinion would be to write something that works for any object you needed to do this for.  Consider the following extension methods...

```
    public static T FromJson<T>(this string jsonData, Encoding encoding = null) 
        where T : class
    {
        encoding = encoding ?? Encoding.Default;
        var deserializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
        var buffer = encoding.GetBytes(jsonData);
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream(buffer))
        {
            return deserializer.ReadObject(stream) as T;
        }
    }

    public static string ToJson<T>(this T obj, Encoding encoding = null) 
        where T : class
    {
        encoding = encoding ?? Encoding.Default;
        var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            serializer.WriteObject(stream, obj);
            return encoding.GetString(stream.ToArray());
        }
    }
```

Usage then looks like this in your case...

```
data: <% = listOfInts.ToJson() %>
```

This works whether you have a List, Int[], or any other object for that matter on your asp.net side.  Also don't forget to consider what encoding your JSON text is in.